# Confusion about maximum output from Geometry Shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

The OpenGL-Wiki states [on the output limitations of geometry shaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader):

> The first limit, defined by `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES`​, is the maximum number that can be provided to the `max_vertices`​ output layout qualifier.
>
> [...]
>
> The other limit, defined by `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS`​ is [...] the total number of output values (a component, in GLSL terms, is a component of a vector. So a float​ is one component; a vec3​ is 3 components).

That's what the declarative part of my geometry shader looks like:

```
layout( triangles ) in;
layout( triangle_strip, max_vertices = 300 ) out;
out vec4 var1;
```

My vertex format only consists of 4 floats for position.
So I believe to have the 4 components from the varying `var1` plus the 4 components from the position, i.e. 8 in total.

I have queried the following values for the constants mentioned above:

```
GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES = 36320
GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS = 36321
```

With `max_vertices` set to 300, a total of 8*300 = 2400 components would be written. It is needless to say that this value is far below 36321 as well as the 300 of `max_vertices` is far below 36320. So everything *should* be okay, right?

However, when I build the shader, the *linking* fails:

> error C6033: Hardware limitation reached, can only emit 128 vertices of this size

Can somebody explain to me what is going on and why this doesn't work as I expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a really dumb mistake. For the record, if somebody else is having the same issue: Querying the values for `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES` and `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS` must be done through `glGetInteger` and not by just evaluating those macros.

Comment: That's a common mistake I guess, but it makes sense as none of the predefined constants can contain information which is specific to the executing hardware.

Comment: Languages like C++ have actual `enum` types to eliminate this problem. But C is pretty lackadaisical, **0x8DE0** (`GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES`) is just an integer as far as its concerned. For future reference, if you see numbers hovering around **36xxx** for some constants, particularly if they are sequential, that's a good sign that you're using the enum value instead of querying the implementation limit ;) Most implementation limits having to do with vectors are powers-of-two, so right off the bat **36320** should look suspicious.

Comment: @Gigo: I wasn't aware that the macros expand to constants, they could as well expand to functions that do the query. This is what I thought.